# Passing data between two views with Xcode 4.6

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios6

I am studying Object-C and I am writing a test app to learn.
This is an easy app, where in the first View i press a button, go in the second View (I used a curl animation)fill a text field and then press a button, pass the content of the field in the first view.

So I created the 2 Views, placed a button and a Label in the first View and linked the button from the first View to the second View using the right mouse click and drag a line with action Modal.

In the second View, I wrote the following code:

ViewController2.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *firstTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *stringFromVC2;

- (IBAction)passTextToVC2Button:(id)sender;
```

ViewController2.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.firstTextField.delegate = self;
}

- (IBAction)passTextToVC2Button:(id)sender {
    ViewController *VC2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"wb_ViewController"];

    VC2.stringFromTextField1 = self.firstTextField.text;

    [self presentViewController:VC2 animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The app works, but when I press the button from ViewController2, and go back to ViewController, it doesn't animate the Curl animation, just it appears from the bottom of the page a new window (the ViewController) under the ViewController opened with the Curl animation.

I also tried to use:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

instead of:

```
[self presentViewController:VC2 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

in this case, it closes the second view but the Label in the first View isn't display with the text I inserted in the second View.

As I told you, I am studying so I am a beginner, please be patient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to define a delegate protocol that your first view controller conforms to, and your second view controller can send a message to to pass back the value.

I've had to answer this question a few times so I created an very simple [example project](https://bitbucket.org/abizern/delegationexample/) to show exactly what I mean. Download it and see how to pass data back down the controller stack.

**Update**

I've changed the sample to an new project for iOS6 with ARC and Storyboards.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I downloaded the project and I have a question. I use the storyboard and I saw you use xib, is it so different? For what I know the storyboard was born to regroup all xib in just one file. Am I wrong?

Comment: You aren't wrong. It's an old example I wrote in 2011. The principle of delegation is the same. I'll try and update the project to iOS 6 and ARC and Storyboards.