# Pass data from a UIViewController to UITabBarController with delegate?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uitabbarcontroller

First of all, I am a beginner of object-c, I am studying it.

I am trying to create an easy app, just to learn the delegate as a guy suggested me in another [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685014/passing-data-between-two-views-with-xcode-4-6).

The situation:
- Storyboard;
- UITabBarController;
- UIViewController.

The app has to start with the Tab Bar Controller (FirstViewController and SecondViewController), from the FirstViewController I want to go to the ViewController (ThirdViewController) and there I have a slider and a back button.
I tried to use the delegate to pass the content of the slider from the ThirdViewController to the FirstViewController.

When I run the app, after the splash screen, it crashes and I have back this message:

> 2013-02-05 19:16:08.382 PassDataBetweenTabsUsingDelegate[3761:c07]
>   -[SecondViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x74c4ed0 2013-02-05 19:16:08.384
>   PassDataBetweenTabsUsingDelegate[3761:c07] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[SecondViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x74c4ed0'

Here is also the [entire project code](http://www.2shared.com/file/60GkdpvW/PassDataBetweenTabsUsingDelega.html), it's faster that copy/paste the part of the code.

Am I doing wrong with the delegate or I don't know the way to tell to the ThirdViewcontroller that it has to go to the First and don't care about the Second?

Comment: Please read this: http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/04/15/passing-data-between-views-tutorial-using-a-protocol-delegate-in-your-iphone-app/    (Your error is that your second view controller doesn't have a delegate property on it, but really you should start with some tutorials)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line :

```
ThirdViewController *svc = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
```

[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] will not return an instance of ThirdViewController since you have not added it in the tab bar. You have just connected the ThirdViewController with the FirstViewController through a modal segue.

What you instead need to do, is create an instance of the ThirdViewController and then set its delegate and then present it modally.

Comment: You can just add a storyboard ID (in the identity inspector) of your ThirdViewController in the storyboard. Then in your FirstViewController use "ThirdViewController *tvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Third"];" , then add delegate : "tvc.delegate = self" and finally present it using "[self presentViewController:animated:completion:]" method. Got it?

Comment: Ye thank, you. Did it in the meanwhile.
Thank you very much for the explanation.